# Name and age application with specific output using arrays and output

Tags: java, arrays, loops

For my university lab work we have to finish 4 tasks. I'm currently on 6 of 9 and have for the most part completed it, but I'm having difficulty in completing the final parts of it. This is the description of what we must do:

> Write a   program that    defines two arrays  -   one of  strings and one of  integers,   both    of  size    10. 
>   Your    program should  then    ask the user    to  enter   the a   string  representing    a   persons name,
>   and an  integer representing    their   age.    It  should  continue    to  do  this    until   either  the **user
>
>   enters  ‘done’** instead    of  a   name,   or  until   the array   is  full    (that   is, 10  pairs   of  names   and ages
>   have    been    entered).   It  should  then    print   out the names   and ages    **as    well    as  the names   of  the 
>   youngest    and oldest.**
>
> Hint: One tricky  part    is  making  sure    that    once    you’ve  typed   ‘done’  to  Finish  entering    names,
>   your    program does    not then    ask you for the age of  the person  with    name    ‘done’  -   be  careful 
>   about   this.

I've highlighted the issues I'm having above in bolded text. Below is the code I currently have, but I'm not sure how to properly accomplish the bolded text.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class nameAge {


public static void main(String[] args){
 String[] name = new String[10];

     int[] age = new int[10];

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String NAME_REQUEST = ("Please enter name");
    String AGE_REQUEST = ("Please enter age");

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of a person and then their age. Do this for up to 10 people and once finished, type 'done'");
    name[0] = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[0] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);
    name[1] = in.next();
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[1] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);
    name[2] = in.next();
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[2] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);
    name[3] = in.next();
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[3] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);
    name[4] = in.next();
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[4] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);
    name[5] = in.next();
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[5] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);
    name[6] = in.next();
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[6] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);
    name[7] = in.next();
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[7] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);
    name[8] = in.next();
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[8] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);
    name[9]= in.next();
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[9] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);


    int size = name.length;
    int sizeN = age.length;

    for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name[i]);
        System.out.println("Age: " + age[i]);
    }
    int smallest = age[0];
    int largetst = age[0];
    for(int i=1; i< age.length; i++)
            {
                    if(age[i] > largetst)
                            largetst = age[i];
                    else if (age[i] < smallest)
                            smallest = age[i];

            }

            System.out.println("Largest Number is : " + largetst);
            System.out.println("Smallest Number is : " + smallest);
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking about homework problems, try to specify _why_ you are having problems with particular areas, so that readers can explain them to you. If you merely get someone to write the code for you, as you have done, you are less likely to learn something. Please also refrain from urgent begging and deadline begging - it is never urgent for volunteers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this out, I have tested it and it's working fine. Hope that helps. Happy coding.

```
package com.pearson.nextgen.aggregatedsessionservice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameAgeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] name = new String[10];
        int[] age = new int[10];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String NAME_REQUEST = "Please enter name";
        String AGE_REQUEST = "Please enter age";

        int count = 0;
        while (count < 10) {
            System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST);

            String nameInput = in.next();
            if (nameInput.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                break;
            }
            name[count] = nameInput;
            System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
            age[count] = in.nextInt();

            count++;
        }

        int[] minAndMaxIndex = findMinAndMaxIndex(age, count);
        System.out.println("Youngest Person: " + name[minAndMaxIndex[0]]);
        System.out.println("Oldest Person: " + name[minAndMaxIndex[1]]);

    }

    private static int[] findMinAndMaxIndex(int[] inputArray, int count) {
        int min, max = 0;
        int minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 0;
        max = min = inputArray[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i] > max)
                maxIndex = i;
            else if (inputArray[i] < min)
                minIndex = i;

        }
        return new int[] { minIndex, maxIndex };
    }

}
```

Comment: With regret I have downvoted, for two reasons. Firstly there is no explanation here as to what you changed or why. Secondly, if you assist someone in cheating on their homework, is that helpful to them? What happens if the OP has to make a defence of their work to a lecturer, and are unable to?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look on  loop doc in java 
this  code may help you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int youngest =0,older=0;
     String[] name = new String[10];
         int[] age = new int[10];
         String NAME_REQUEST = ("Please enter name");
         String AGE_REQUEST = ("Please enter age");

    for(int i=0 ; i< 10;i++){
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println(NAME_REQUEST); 
    String tmpName = in.nextLine();
    if(tmpName.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))
    break;
    name[i] = tmpName;
    System.out.println(AGE_REQUEST);
    age[i] = in.nextInt();
    if(age[i] > age[older])
    older = i;
    if(age[i] < age[youngest])
    youngest = i;

    }

     System.out.println("OLDER is  : " + name[older]);
     System.out.println("Younger : " + name[youngest]);
}
```